# VBA Paste Plain Text To Outlook Email Body

Tags: excel, vba, text, outlook

I currently have a working VBA code that pastes a table as HTML into the body section of a new outlook email. The HTML seems to be causing some issues for the engine reading these emails, and so I am trying to amend the code to paste the table as plain text in the body, rather than HTML, but I can't find any examples of VBA to outlook code that pastes a range as text, only a single cell. Does anybody know how I can adapt this code for plain text?

Code below:

```
Sub Auto_Send_Data()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sample Tab").Select
    Range("B4:B31").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Tab").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object


Set rng = Nothing
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.

'this uses the current selection
'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'This is if you have a specific range you want to use
Set rng = Sheets("Other Tab").Range("A1:B30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


With OutMail
    .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Tab").Range("F1").Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Tab").Range("F2").Value
    .HTMLBody = msg1
    ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
    ' display the e-mail message.
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: After reading the text file try RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML vbCrLf, "<br>")

Comment: The CRLF in the text needs to be replaced by <br> (new row)

Answer (score 1):

- The only modification is the substitution of `RangetoHTML` with a UDF called `RangetoText` to generate a plain text string.

```vb
Function RangetoText(ByVal rngData As Range) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arrData, arrRes
    Const DEL_CHAR = vbTab
    If rngData.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        RangetoText = rngData.Value
    Else
        arrData = rngData.Value
        ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData))
        For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
            For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
                arrRes(i) = arrRes(i) & DEL_CHAR & arrData(i, j)
            Next j
            arrRes(i) = Mid(arrRes(i), 2)
        Next i
        RangetoText = Join(arrRes, vbCrLf)
    End If
End Function
```

---

Sample data:

|  | Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B1 | C1 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 |
| 3 | A3 | B3 | C3 |

```vb
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print "--Single cell--"
    Debug.Print RangetoText(Range("A1"))
    Debug.Print "--Single column--"
    Debug.Print RangetoText(Range("A1:A3"))
    Debug.Print "--Single row--"
    Debug.Print RangetoText(Range("A1:C1"))
    Debug.Print "--Cells range--"
    Debug.Print RangetoText(Range("A1:C3"))
End Sub
```

Ouput:

```
--Single cell--
A1
--Single column--
A1
A2
A3
--Single row--
A1  B1  C1
--Cells range--
A1  B1  C1
A2  B2  C2
A3  B3  C3
```